# modal discord is not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a problem with a modal on the code if below which is a / command file. The modal appears but when I try to enter the values ​​the following error message appears (see image), I use discord.js V14.9. Could you help me?

```
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  Client,
  ButtonStyle,
  TextInputBuilder,
  MessageActionRow,
  MessageSelectMenu,
  MessageButton,
  SelectMenuBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  MessageButtonbuilder,
  ActionRowBuilder,
  MessageSelectMenuBuilder,
  ModalBuilder,
  SelectMenu,
  Events,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  TextInputStyle,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
} = require('@discordjs/builders');

const discipline = 'selectdiscipline';

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('créer-course').setDescription('Crée une course'),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const buttoncourse = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('buttoncourse')
      .setLabel('créer une course')
      .setStyle('Primary');

    const buttonRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(buttoncourse);

    const modalCourse = new ModalBuilder()
    .setCustomId('courseModal')
    .setTitle('Information pour la création de la course')
    .addComponents(
      new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId('nameInput')
          .setLabel('Nom de la course (Lieu, Type)')
          .setStyle('Short')
      ),
      new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId('dateInput')
          .setLabel('Date de la course ( xx/xx/xxxx )')
          .setStyle('Short')
      ),
      new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new TextInputBuilder()
          .setCustomId('nameRespInput')
          .setLabel('Nom du responsable de la course')
          .setStyle('Short')
      ),
      );
      
      const selectDiscipline = new SelectMenuBuilder()
          .setCustomId('selectDiscipline')
          .setPlaceholder('Sélectionner une discipline')
          .addOptions([
            { label: 'Slalom', value: 'slalom' },
            { label: 'Course en ligne', value: 'course_en_ligne' },
            { label: 'Kayak Polo', value: 'kayak_polo' },
            { label: 'Descente', value: 'descente' },
            { label: 'Dragon boat', value: 'dragon_boat' },
            { label: 'Freestyle', value: 'freestyle' },
            { label: 'Paracanoë', value: 'paracanoë' },
            { label: 'Océan racing', value: 'ocean_racing' },
            { label: 'Marathon', value: 'marathon' },
            { label: 'Raft', value: 'raft' },
            { label: 'Waveski-surfing', value: 'waveski_surfing' },
            { label: 'Stand-up-paddle', value: 'stand_up_paddle' },
          ]);

    const courseFilter = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && ['buttoncourse'].includes(i.customId);
    const courseCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: courseFilter});

    const filterModal = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && ['courseModal'].includes(i.customId);
    const collectorModal = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filterModal, time: 600000 });

    const filterDiscipline = i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id && ['courseModal'].includes(i.customId);
    const collectorDiscipline = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filterDiscipline, time: 600000 });

    await interaction.reply({
      content: ` Clicker pour commencer à créer une course `,
      components: [buttonRow],
    });
    
    courseCollector.on('collect', async i => {
      if (!i.isButton()) return;
    
      if (i.customId === 'buttoncourse') {
        await i.showModal(modalCourse);
      }
    });
    
    collectorModal.on('collect', async i => {
      if (!i.isModalSubmit()) return;
    
      if (i.customId === 'courseModal') {
        const courseName = i.fields.getTextInputValue('nameInput');
        const date = i.fields.getTextInputValue('dateInput');
        const respName = i.fields.getTextInputValue('nameRespInput');
  
        await i.reply({ content: 'Les informations ont bien été récupérées!', ephemeral: true });
      }
    });

    collectorDiscipline.on('collect', async i => {
      if (!i.isModalSubmit()) return;

      if (i.customId === 'selectDiscipline') {
        const discipline = i.fields.getTextInputValue('selectDiscipline');
  
        await i.reply({ content: 'Création de la course en cours ...', ephemeral: true });
        await createCourse(interaction, courseName, date, respName);
      }
  });

    async function createCourse(interaction, discipline, courseName, date, respName) {
        const roleNames = {
    organizer: `Organisateur ${courseName}`,
    parcours: `Parcours ${courseName}`,
    judges: `Juges ${courseName}`,
    runners: `Coureurs & Invités ${courseName}`,
  };
  
  const courseType = discipline;

  const category = await interaction.guild.channels.create(courseName, { type: 'GUILD_CATEGORY' });

  const organizerRole = await interaction.guild.roles.create({ name: roleNames.organizer });
  await interaction.member.roles.add(organizerRole);

  const parcoursRole = await interaction.guild.roles.create({ name: roleNames.parcours });
  const judgesRole = await interaction.guild.roles.create({ name: roleNames.judges });
  const runnersRole = await interaction.guild.roles.create({ name: roleNames.runners });

  const infoChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create('Information-Course', { type: ChannelType.GuildText, parent: category });
  const departChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create('liste-de-départ', { type: ChannelType.GuildText, parent: category });
  const penaliteChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create('fiches-pénalité', { type: ChannelType.GuildText, parent: category });
  const resultChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create('résultats', { type: ChannelType.GuildText, parent: category });
  const judgeChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create('discussion-juges', { type: ChannelType.GuildText, parent: category });
  const openCloseChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create('ouvrir-et-terminer-la-course', { type: ChannelType.GuildText, parent: category });

  const channels = [infoChannel, departChannel, penaliteChannel, resultChannel, judgeChannel];

for (const channel of channels) {
  await channel.permissionOverwrites.set([
    {
      id: organizerRole.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_ROLES'],
    },
    {
      id: parcoursRole.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
    },
    {
      id: judgesRole.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
    },
    {
      id: runnersRole.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
    },
    {
      id: interaction.guild.id,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ]);
}

// Appliquer les permissions spécifiques pour le channel "discussion-juges"
await judgeChannel.permissionOverwrites.set([
  {
    id: judgesRole.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
  {
    id: interaction.guild.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
]);

// Appliquer les permissions spécifiques pour le channel "ouvrir-et-terminer-la-course"
await openCloseChannel.permissionOverwrites.set([
  {
    id: organizerRole.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
  {
    id: interaction.guild.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
]);

// Envoyer des messages d'introduction dans les channels
await infoChannel.send(`**Informations sur la course ${courseName}**\nDiscipline: ${discipline}\nDate: ${date}\nResponsable: ${respName}`);
await departChannel.send(`**Liste de départ pour la course ${courseName}**`);
await penaliteChannel.send(`**Fiches de pénalité pour la course ${courseName}**`);
await resultChannel.send(`**Résultats pour la course ${courseName}**`);
await judgeChannel.send(`**Discussion entre les juges pour la course ${courseName}**`);
await openCloseChannel.send(`**Ouvrir et terminer la course ${courseName}**`);

const openCloseRow = new MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId("open_course")
      .setLabel("Ouvrir la course")
      .setStyle("Success"),
    new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId("close_course")
      .setLabel("Terminer la course")
      .setStyle("Danger")
  );

await openCloseChannel.send({
  content: "Utilisez les boutons ci-dessous pour ouvrir ou fermer la course:",
  components: [openCloseRow],
});

    const openCloseFilter = (i) =>
    i.user.id === interaction.user.id &&
    ["open_course", "close_course"].includes(i.customId);

  const openCloseCollector = openCloseChannel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter: openCloseFilter,
  });

openCloseCollector.on("collect", async (i) => {


  if (i.customId === "open_course") {
    await i.update({
      content: `La course ${courseName} est maintenant ouverte.`,
      components: [],
    });
  
    const joinRunnersFilter = (i) => i.customId === 'join_runners_role' && !i.user.bot;

    
        // Gérer les actions lorsque la course est ouverte
        const channelIdMap = {
          "slalom": "1074322574919618611",
          "course en ligne": "1074322656960204800",
          "polo": "1074322787310772224",
          "descente": "1074322830314983424",
          "dragon boat": "1074322962351673384",
          "freestyle": "1074323060146044978",
          "paraconoë": "1074323137543549019",
          "océan racing": "1074323232661966981",
          "marathon": "1074323270230364180",
          "raft": "1074323316560633856",
          "waveski surfing": "1074323404896866456",
          "stand up padle": "1074323471435321434",
        };
    
        const targetChannelId = channelIdMap[courseType.toLowerCase()];
        const targetChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.fetch(targetChannelId);
    
        const joinRoleRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
          new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("join_runners_role")
            .setLabel("Obtenir le rôle runners")
            .setStyle("Primary")
        );
    
        const entryMessage = await targetChannel.send({
          content: `**Rejoignez la course ${courseName} en cliquant sur le bouton ci-dessous pour obtenir le rôle "runners".**`,
          components: [joinRoleRow],
        });
    
        const joinRunnersCollector = targetChannel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: joinRunnersFilter});
      }
});
joinRunnersCollector.on('collect', async (i) => {
  const runnerRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'runners');

  if (!runnerRole) {
    console.error("Le rôle 'runners' est introuvable. Assurez-vous qu'il existe sur le serveur.");
    return;
  }

  if (i.member.roles.cache.has(runnerRole.id)) {
    await i.reply({
      content: `Vous avez déjà le rôle 'runners' de la course ${courseName} .`,
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  } else {
    await i.member.roles.add(runnerRole);
    await i.reply({
      content: `Vous avez obtenu le rôle 'runners' de la course ${courseName} .`,
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});
joinRunnersCollector.on('end', (collected) => {
  console.log(`Le collecteur de boutons 'join_runners_role' a été arrêté après ${collected.size} interactions.`);
});

    if (i.customId === 'close_course') {
      // Supprimer tous les rôles de la course
      const roleNames = ['runners', 'organizers', 'judges', 'parcours'];
      roleNames.forEach(async (roleName) => {
        const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName);
        if (role) {
          await role.delete(`Suppression du rôle ${roleName} pour la course ${courseName}`);
        }
      });
    
      // Supprimer les salons (infoChannel, departChannel, penaliteChannel, resultChannel, judgeChannel, openCloseChannel)
      channels.forEach(async (channel) => {
        if (channel) {
          await channel.delete(`Suppression du salon ${channel.name} pour la course ${courseName}`);
        }
      });
    
      // Supprimer la catégorie de la course
      if (categoryChannel) {
        await categoryChannel.delete(`Suppression de la catégorie ${categoryChannel.name} pour la course ${courseName}`);
      }
    
      // Supprimer le message d'entrée de la course
      if (entryMessage) {
        await entryMessage.delete();
      }
    
      // Informer l'utilisateur que la course a été fermée
      await i.reply(`La course ${courseName} a été fermée et tous les éléments associés ont été supprimés.`);
    };

    openCloseCollector.on("end", async () => {
      await openCloseChannel.send({
          content: `La gestion de l'ouverture et de la fermeture de la course ${courseName} est terminée.`,
      });
  });
}
}
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFTRw.png)

I looked in the logs but nothing, no error message in the console